# Java - Two threads communicating via wait()/notify() but threads are alternating on with thread gets lock first

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

The desired output of this programme is:

Ping
Pong
Ping
Pong
Ping
Pong

Yet it alternates between that and

Pong
Ping 
etc.

The thing is, I create the Ping thread and run it first. So I am not sure why Pong is occassionally coming first.

So here is my code (readily compilable). It works, essentially. I just don't understand why it sometimes prints "Pong" first. Could someone please shed some light as to why this is happening?

```
// Printer class - will be the object that both threads lock / synchronize onto
class Printer
{
    int numberOfMessages;
    int messageCount;

    // Constructor allowing user to choose how many messages are displayed
    Printer(int numberOfMessages)
    {       
        this.numberOfMessages = numberOfMessages;
        this.messageCount = 0;
    }

    // If more messages are to be printed, print and increment messageCount
    void printMsg(String msg)
    {
        if (messageCount < numberOfMessages)
        {
            System.out.println("[" + msg + "]");            
            ++messageCount;
        }
        else
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

// PingPong thread
class PingPongThread extends Thread
{
    Printer printer;
    String message; 

    public PingPongThread(Printer printer, String message)
    {
        this.printer = printer;
        this.message = message;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (printer)
            {                   
                // Print message whether it is Ping or Pong
                printer.printMsg(message);

                // Notify
                printer.notify();

                // Wait
                try
                {
                    printer.wait();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {               
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

// Two threads communicate with eachother to alteratively print out "Ping" and "Pong"
public class PingPong
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Printer printer = new Printer(6);

        PingPongThread pingThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Ping");
        PingPongThread pongThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Pong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it not happen?

Comment: I didn't formulate the question properly. I create Ping thread first and class start() in the Ping constructor. The run method includes print "Ping" statement. As this is done first, I can't see why Pong is sometimes printed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
    Printer printer = new Printer(6);
    PingPongThread pingThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Ping");
    synchronized (printer) {
        printer.wait();
    }
    PingPongThread pongThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Pong");
```

will guarantee that pingThread always starts first.

Nevertheless the threads coordination still depends on who runs faster. Consider this

```
final Object obj = new Object();
Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            obj.notify();
        }
    };
};

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            try {
                obj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
};

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

if t1 notifies before t2 goes waiting the test hangs.

Comment: imagine thread1 calls printer.notify(); thread2 gets notification and comes to print.notify() before thread2 calls printer.wait(); See my point? My test shows what happens - notification is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Because `run` method runs in a different thread, and you cannot assume which one will run first unless you have proper synchronisation. If thread started first it doesn't mean that it will be more important. *All animals are equal.*

You should create a special flag in the thread which is notified when a thread starts. And wait for the flag before starting the second thread. Simple way to do it is to use [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

Answer (score 1):

You want to force threads run order. The JVM does not guarantee that, so you have to roll your own. I can think of two solutions.

Ugly hack, but may work: Yield the current thread after starting the first thread but before starting the second one, to "encourage" it to run. E.g:

```
PingPongThread pingThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Ping");
Thread.yield();
PingPongThread pongThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Pong");
```

This is the simplest solution but it is not guaranteed to work every time, e.g., if another thread (say, an event handler) will grab the control after the yield.

A more robust approach: Have the main thread wait for some other signal before starting the second thread. Suppose this signal is passed through a field named `lock`, this will look something like:

```
Object lock = new Object();
PingPongThread pingThread = new PingPongThread(lock, printer, "Ping");
lock.wait();
PingPongThread pongThread = new PingPongThread(lock, printer, "Pong");
```

and the thread `run()` method will be something like

```
synchronize (lock) { lock.notify(); }
while (true) {
  // As before...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JVM does not provide any guarantee that threads will start in the order they are started. That is why sometimes 2nd thread starts first.

Answer (score 1):

If you create two threads, e.g. `t1` and `t2`, and then invoke:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

it does not mean that `t1` will start executing before `t2`. It might, but there is a chance `t2` will start first. You'll have to write your own approach that gurantees `t1` starts first. For example, after starting the first thread, `wait()` on an object, and in the first thread `notify()` on that object at the beginning of `run()`

Answer (score 0):

As @evgeniy already pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807013/java-two-threads-communicating-via-wait-notify-but-threads-are-alternating#comment22483473_15807593): the answer marked as solution has a flaw. A possible solution is locking the `printer` *before* starting the first thread, thus it cannot enter it's synchronized section until `printer.wait()` is called.

```
Printer printer = new Printer(6);
synchronized (printer) {
    PingPongThread pingThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Ping");
    printer.wait();
}
PingPongThread pongThread = new PingPongThread(printer, "Pong");
```